# 2 verbs in a sentence

Tags: grammar

The sentence is as follows
*He recently noticed something abnormal about the way this present generation of teens is developing.*

In the sentence, why are there 2 verbs, *notice* & *is* in the sentence?
Is it correct?
Could anyone please help me to get point?
Many thanks.

Comment: You sentence before last contains three verbs: _could_, _help_ and _get_. Why would that be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two separate subjects in the sentence, the first being "He" and the second being "Teens". *Noticed* pertains to the main subject "He" and *Is* pertains to the secondary subject "Teens".

Comment: Thank you. So I can take the sentence as two parts. "He recently noticed something abnormal about the way" & "this present generation of teens is developing.".  May I add "that" between two parts ?